# link_to for url with embedded parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still newish to rails so not sure on the correct terms here but..

I'd like to see how you use the link_to helper when your url has parameters embedded in the structure.

Such as:

```
http://example.com/appointments/2015/3/15
```

Which then displays appointments for a certain day.  How do you use link to when you know the date but need to pass it in as part of the URL?

something like, link_to 'Text', appointments_path(2015/3/15) or whatever it is?

Sorry I'm unsure the terms here or else I could probably find it better with google

Bonus: What do you call this type of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a route with [dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) like:

```
get '/appointments/:year/:month/:date', to: 'appointments#index', as: :appointments
```

You just pass the year, month, and day parameters as arguments to the path helper:

```
link_to appointments_path(year: 2015, month: 3, day: 15)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Do you know what this is called? What type of url structure with parameters in it?

Comment: These are called [dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments)

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom your route

```
get 'appointments/:year/:month/:day', to: 'appointments#show'
```

...

```
appointments_path(year: '2015', month: '3', day: '15')
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use the `show` action for showing multiple appointments on the same day.  `index` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the rails docs for `link_to` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Specifically you can use the following example for a `profile` object:

`link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)`

which gives you:

`<a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>`

Comment: i'm unclear how this in anyway answers my question? Can you go into detail? I'm asking about a very specific type of URL not just the basic example

Comment: I'm assuming url has path like /:year_no/:month_no/:day_no ... you can pass in multiple values to the url helper